# Express documentation

Tags: node.js, express

I have just started studying node.js and express, the documentation of express on the home page is just too simple for me as a beginner.

for example,

```
app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    ...
});
```

It may seems very obvious to you, but I just wonder what **express.static** mean? I can't find an answer by searching Google.

This is just one example that I can't understand the code.

So is there any better documentation of express for the absolute beginner?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that the Express documentation reads a bit more like a book than an API doc. In the case of `express.static`, this is a re-expored middleware from Connect (`connect.static`), which Express is built on. From [the middleware section of the docs](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#middleware):

> Typically with connect middleware you would require(‘connect’) like so:
>
> ```
> var connect = require('connect');
> app.use(connect.logger());
> app.use(connect.bodyParser());
> ```
>
> This is somewhat annoying, so express re-exports these middleware properties, however they are identical:
>
> ```
> app.use(express.logger());
> app.use(express.bodyParser());
> ```

You can see what middleware Connect exposes on [their web site](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/). In particular, check out the documentation for [the static middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I know the code more clearly, but still, this can't solve my initial problem: is there better book/tutorial/documentation about express?

Comment: I don't know of any definite sources. Understanding Connect and the middleware stack goes a long way to understanding Express; everything else is experience and reading code. :)

Comment: Agreed. You can basically think of the Connect middleware documentation as more documentation for Express.js.

Answer (score 0):

`express` is the [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29) and `static` is a member of that class. What `express.static` means is "use the *static* method of the *express* class", what the `static` method does is initialize a static file server to be served by your node.js server.